# What expression will give age in years in QGIS?

Tags: qgis-plugins

I have the date at which a pipe was laid. I want to create a field giving the age of the pipe in years. How do I do this in QGIS?

Comment: Can you please give an example of age and corresponding year ?

Answer (score 5):

Or use the `age` function

```
year(age(now() ,"yourdatefield"))
```

Comment: Sometimes I get comfortable using some function and just forget that there might be another one that saves some time... :P

Answer (score 2):

From the field calculator, this expression could do the trick:

`year(now()) - year('the laying date')`

Check if the date format will work, but aside from that, it should be pretty easy. The laying date can be replaced by a field value.